# How to change table layout depending on resolution?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So this is targeted toward IE 10 and 11 and I'm also using Bootstrap 3.

If I have a desktop monitor, I'd like my table to have this layout:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Header 1</td>
         <td>Header 2</td>
         <td>Header 3</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot></tfoot>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Data 1</td>
         <td>Data 2</td>
         <td>Data 3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

On a phone (or similar device), I'd like to have the layout like this:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Header</td>
         <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot></tfoot>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Header 1</td>
         <td>Data 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Header 2</td>
         <td>Data 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Header 3</td>
         <td>Data 3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there some  or CSS that will allow me to do this? Or can this only be done with javascript (and css)?

To be clear, I want the code to detect the resolution and display one of the two layouts.

Comment: Have you tried searching for javascript code that switches rows and columns?

Comment: why don't you just use bootstrap classes. Do you really need to change table structure?

Comment: You won't be able to restructure your table with CSS. One alternative, that I'm a bit `meh` about is including the two versions of the table into your page and only displaying one at a time depending on viewport size. This technique is sometimes used with navigation menus.

Comment: @AlFra - could you elaborate on that? Which classes should I be using?

Comment: sorry @DaBest. It was mistake-a to make-a :D I didn't explored your question enough. You can not do what you ask with just bootstrap classes (i had pull and push in mind) There could be a JavaScript solution. but it could be quite messy one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two tables and use css media queries to toggle between the two, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5f3pbg8b/17/

```
.table.mobile {
  display: none
}

.table.desktop {
  display: inline
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .table.desktop {
    display: none
  }
  .table.mobile {
    display: inline
  }
}
```